# moment(?).year(?).week(?).weekday(?).format('MM/DD/YYYY') not working in December

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

The issue is specific to moment.year()

I am trying to get the beginning date of the next week based on the current date. It works well except for the last month of the year. The example should explain.

```
new Date(moment(1577379939000).year(2020).week(1).weekday(0).format('MM/DD/YYYY'))
Sun Dec 29 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

This gives me Sun Dec 29 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) 29th dec 2019 as begining of the next week(sunday)
This is correct 
1577379939000 is 26th of December 2019(Thursday).

However, if the input is 1577466306000 which is 27th of December 2019(Friday)
it gives me 2020 December date, not 2019

```
new Date(moment(1577466306000).year(2020).week(1).weekday(0).format('MM/DD/YYYY'))
Sun Dec 27 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

If it is moment.js error. is there any workaround?

Comment: It sounds more like a bug report. Can't you just hack your way around?

Comment: Your (lack of) formatting makes this very difficult to understand

Comment: the `.week(1)` is where it fails by the way - looks like a bug in momentjs - it also breaks on different day, depending on your timezone - i.e. for me both of those inputs give the wrong answer, I had to go back one more day to get the right answer (I'm in UTC+11)

Comment: it has something to do with the fact the ISO spec says week 1 is the week with Jan 4 in it or something like that

Comment: By the way, your code is flawed for what you want to do ... for example it produces 29th December for EVERY input date (except for the input dates 26th to 30th december)

Comment: to do what you are describing, you only need to use `.weekday(7)` - this will give you the what you describe in your first sentence what you're trying to do ...  *"get the beginning date of the next week"*

Comment: Watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3jxx8Yyw1c and understand - but still, what you are describing you want to do is far simpler than what you are doing :p

Answer (score 1):

Try to use weekYear instead of year

Answer (score 0):

I think this is working as intended. After you use `.year(2020)` you're changing the dates to December 2020. This is the calendary for that month:

```
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  
       1  2  3  4  5  
 6  7  8  9 10 11 12  
13 14 15 16 17 18 19  
20 21 22 23 24 25 26  
27 28 29 30 31
```

In the United States, `moment.js` defines weeks to start on Sunday, and week 1 is the week containing January 1. So the week beginning with December 27 is actually week 1 of 2021.

That means that when you call `.week(1)`, it doesn't change anything for December 27, and returns a date in December 2020 when you call `.weekday(0)`.

But December 26 is in week 26 of 2020, so calling `.week(1)` changes the date to Saturday in week 1 of 2020, which is January 4. Then calling `.weekday(0)` returns the Sunday before that, which is December 29, 2019.

As mentioned in a comment, the way to get the first day of the next week after a given date, just use `.weekday(7)`.

```
new Date(moment(1577466306000).weekday(7))
```

I'm not sure why you're specifying a particular year or week number.

Comment: Because we time travel. 
We do not go by the system date. we pick the date from the server. The Date can be either past or future. This means we have to pick the year from the server, not from the logged-in device.